# Is there a client (JS) API for interacting with PWA permissions? Namely, PWA Groups and Categories

Tags: permissions, client-object-model, project-server, api

We're starting to play around with Project Server (on-prem) using Project Server permission mode (as opposed to SharePoint permission mode).

We need to be able to segregate the .mpp files so that certain planners have acces to some files, and other planners have access to others.

For instance, we might have multiple project "trees" where there is a master file and a couple linked sub-project files:

- Project_A_Master

  - Project_A_Sub1
  - Project_A_Sub2
- Project_B_Master

  - Project_B_Sub1
  - Project_B_Sub2

That's 3 files per "project".  We can achieve what we want by creating a PWA "Category" called "Project A files" and including the three Project A .mpp files in that category, then creating a group called "Project A Planners", and include all users who should have access to the Project A files in that group, and give that group access to the "Project A files" category.

But what if we want to add a new user to the group, or if there is a new sub-project file that needs to be added to the category?

Is ther an API we can use to make those changes (given the right permissions, of course) in a simple client UI, so that we don't have to have an Admin constantly go into "PWA Settings" to do it?

I've looked through a bunch of documentation for the Project Server REST API and the `PS.js` namespace, and I haven't seen anything yet for this kind of thing.